# Get highlighted text from any window (javascript)

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is it possible to get the highlighted text from another window than the active one in a browser with the use of Javascript? Something like this:

```
keyword = window.getSelection().toString();
use(keyword);
```

This I can use for the current document, but I would like to get text from other sources.

Comment: Do you have a variable that holds the other window? In general, you can only get a window into a variable if you opened it with `window.open()`. And you won't be able to access anything in the other window if the document is in a different domain.

Comment: And in case you've got this variable and can access it (no cross-origin issue), you just need to do `otherWindow.getSelection().toString()`. In case of cross-domain windows, but that you do control both, you can also use the [`postMessage` API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage).

Comment: Or create a bookmarklet but you need somewhere to send that data to

Comment: @Kaiido depends on use case which is unknown. But you can run script in a bookmarklet on any page and yes it would require running it in that browser tab but so does creating a selection

Comment: @Kaiido am assuming that the selection is make manually which is most typical use case for needing getSelection()

Answer (score 0):

You will probably need to build a browser extension/plugin.
Else you wont be able to get any data from another open window or tab.